# Vectorize 3D discrete Fourier transform

Tags: linear-algebra, fourier-transform, vectorization

I'm trying to express the $N$-dimensional discrete Fourier transform (DFT) of an $N$-dimensional array as the product between a matrix and a vector.

If $N=2$ the problem is quite simple: given a $n\times m$ matrix $X$, since $DFT(X) = F_nXF_m^T = F_nXF_m$ (where $F_h$ is the $h \times h$ Fourier matrix) and since $vec(AXB)=(A^T \otimes B)vec(X)$, the desired matrix is $F_n\otimes F_m$ and the vector is $vec(X)$, so that

$$vec(DFT(X)) = (F_n \otimes F_m) vec(X)$$

What can be done if $N\geq 3$, especially if $N=3$?

EDIT: let me better specify the notation, by using MATLAB conventions. An $N$-dimensional array $X$ is a function from $\{1,\dots,n_1\} \times \{1, \dots, n_2\} \times \dots \times \{1, \dots, n_N\}$ to $\mathbb C$. In MATLAB notation, one can access its elements by $X(i_1, i_2, \dots, i_n)$ with suitable indices $i_j$.

The $N$-dimensional DFT of an $N$-dimensional array $X$ is exactly what MATLAB does by typing `fftn(X)`. [More details here](https://it.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fftn.html).

Instead of calculating the $N$-dimensional DFT in $N$ steps by applying the 1-D DFT along each dimension, I would like to find a "one shot" matrix-vector product formulation of this operation. A procedure like

1. Unwrap vector $X$ to a vectorized form;
2. Multiply $X$ by a suitable matrix;
3. Wrap back $X$ to an $N$ dimensional array form;
4. The output is the same as `fftn(X)`.

This need comes from the study of a 3-D imaging problem where the 3-D image has to be reconstructed from an underdetermined set of measurements using a particular solving procedure. The matrix I'm trying to obtain with your help is (almost) the matrix I will use in the solving procedure.

Comment: The transform is separable over dimensions so you can factor it over dimensions and use kronecker product to encode dimensions in the vectorization. Assuming $M_k$ is the data points in dimension $k$ ; $I_{M_1} \otimes \cdots \otimes I_{M_n}$ and just replace the $I_{M_k}$ with the Fourier transform matrix for dimension $k$ where $k$ is the dimension you want to transform.

Comment: The $N$-dimensional discrete Fourier transform is a standard procedure. But it seems you are using some strange notation. E.g., what is the "Fourier matrix"? The standard way of dealing with these things would look like $\hat X=FX$, or similar.

Comment: I edited the question and added further details to clarify the setting.

Comment: That one-shot matrix-vector product is not necessarily faster than applying FFT for each dimension though. Is there something about the matrix that's interesting for your problem?

Comment: Yes there is! I'm solving a radar imaging problem where the solution is expected to be sparse. I'm comparing the classical method of applying DFTs along the various dimensions against other iterative methods (from the galaxy of compressed sensing) that rely on the sparsity of the solution. These methods however need to wotk on the full matrix of the system.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Suppose $\mathcal{X}\in \mathbb{C}^{I_{1} \times I_{2} \times\dots \times I_{n}} $ is an $\text{n}^\text{th}$ order complex-valued tensor which is your original signal. If you want to get its n-dimensional discrete Fourier transform $\mathcal{Y}\in \mathbb{C}^{I_{1} \times I_{2} \times\dots \times I_{n}} $, you can write this as follows
$$  \mathcal{Y}(j_{1},j_{2},\dots,j_{n}) = \sum_{i_{n}=1}^{I_{n}} F_{I_{n}}(j_{n},i_{n}) \dots \sum_{i_{2}=1}^{I_{2}} F_{I_{2}}(j_{2},i_{2}) \sum_{i_{1}=1}^{I_{1}} F_{I_{1}}(j_{1},i_{1})\mathcal{X}(i_{1},i_{2},\dots,i_{n})$$
where $$F_{I_{k}}(j_{k},i_{k}) = \exp \left (-\frac{2\pi i}{I_{k}} (j_{k}-1)(i_{k}-1)\right) \quad \forall k \in \{1,2,\dots,n\}$$
with $i$ being the imaginary unit. 
In tensor notation, this summation can be expressed with successive k-mode products which is defined as
$$ \mathcal{B} = \mathcal{A} \times_{k} \mathbf{U} \iff \mathcal{B}(i_1,\dots,i_{k-1},j,i_{k+1},\dots,i_{n}) = \sum_{i_{k}=1}^{I_{k}}U(j,i_k)\mathcal{A}(i_1,\dots,i_{k-1},i_{k},i_{k+1},\dots,i_{n})$$
for any $\mathcal{A}\in \mathbb{C}^{I_{1} \times\dots \times I_{k-1} \times I_{k} \times I_{k+1} \times \dots \times I_{n}}$ and $\mathbf{U}\in\mathbb{C}^{J\times I_{k}} $ yielding $\mathcal{B}\in \mathbb{C}^{I_{1} \times\dots \times I_{k-1} \times J \times I_{k+1} \times \dots \times I_{n}}$

The final closed form n-dimensional discrete Fourier transform can be written as 
$$ \mathcal{Y} = \mathcal{X}\times_{1}\mathbf{F}_{I_1}\times_{2}\mathbf{F}_{I_1}\times_{3}\dots\times_{n}\mathbf{F}_{I_n}$$ Vectorization of each side results in 
$$ \mathbf{y} =\text{vec}(\mathcal{Y}),\mathbf{x} =\text{vec}(\mathcal{X}) \quad \text{then} \quad \mathbf{y}=( \mathbf{F}_{I_n} \otimes \dots \otimes \mathbf{F}_{I_2} \otimes \mathbf{F}_{I_1})\mathbf{x}$$ 
where $\otimes$ is Kronecker product. So, your original question for 3D DFT can be solved as
$$ \mathbf{x}^{*} = \text{3D-DFT}(\mathbf{x}) =(\mathbf{F}_{M} \otimes \mathbf{F}_{L} \otimes \mathbf{F}_{K})\mathbf{x}$$
for $\mathbf{x} =\text{vec}(\mathcal{X})$ and $\mathcal{X} \in \mathbb{C}^{K\times L\times M}$.